# Is the fundamental system correct ?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> Let $\dot x=Ax$ with $A\in\Bbb R^{3x3}$.
>
> I wanted to calculate the fundamental system, but not sure if it's right:

$1)$ Calculating the eigenvalues
$\Rightarrow$ $\lambda_1=3$ with multiplicy $m_1=1$ and $\lambda_2=0$ with $m_2=2$

$2)$ Calculating (generalized) eigenvectors
$v_1=\begin{pmatrix}-1\\1\\0\end{pmatrix},v_2=\begin{pmatrix}-1\\0\\1\end{pmatrix},v_3=e^{3t}\begin{pmatrix}1\\1\\1\end{pmatrix}$

$3)$Diagonalize $A$ such that $A=T\begin{pmatrix}0&0&0\\0&0&0\\0&0&3\end{pmatrix}T^{-1}$ with $T=(v_1\quad v_2\quad v_3)$

Hence $e^{tA}=Te^{tJ}T^{-1}=T\begin{pmatrix}1&0&0\\1&0&0\\0&0&e^{3t}\end{pmatrix}T^{-1}$

So is the fundamental system $\{v_1,v_2,v_3\}$ or $e^{tA}?$

Thanks in advance

Comment: In both of the two books I have, $e^{At}$ is defined to be the fundamental matrix. I didn't find the definition for "fundamental system". What is the definition of it in your book?

Comment: It's the set of soultions - the vectors together are the fundamental matrix

Comment: If the fundamental system is defined to be the fundamental set of solutions, then it should be $e^{tA}C$ for any constant vector $C$.

Comment: @KittyL:OK;thanks